# Configure Webpack to serve react at relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, koa

I have a koajs server that serves react as static files from the /dist folder.

```
const static_pages = new Koa();
static_pages.use(serve(process.env.PWD + "/dist")); 
app.use(mount("/app", static_pages));
```

The problem is that, I want to mount the index.html from /dist at the relative path "/app" because at "/" i have something else.
My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
  entry: "./static/index.js",
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "[name].js"
  },
```

where ***static/index.js*** is my react app. And when i open the browser i get an 500 error

> "http://localhost:4000/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server
> Error)"

But if i go to ***localhost:4000/app/main.js*** it works, i get the ***main.js*** bundled file, but my ***index.html*** from dist tries to get main.js not ***/app/main.js.***

How I'm supposed to change the webpack config file bundle it so that my app will be mounted at relative path?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use React + Koa at the development you should use `webpack-dev-server` to serve you're react bundle with HRM on a specified PORT, otherwise if you're willing to sever static build from React.js files you should use [`koa-static`](https://github.com/koajs/static) middleware which will allow you to serve bundle.

According to your webpack configuration, you're missing important `html-webpack-plugin` which will generate an `index.html` in your bundle (without that `koa` isn't able to serve content on specified path).

Answer (score 0):

```
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./static/index.html", 
  filename: "./index.html"
});
```

This is my HtmlWbpackPlugin configuration. I've managed to solve the issue by adding publigPath to the output like that:

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: '/app'
  },
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but it works